# QML TypeError: Property 'xx' of object yy is not a function

Tags: qt, qml

I have this main.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.13
import QtQuick.Window 2.13
import QtQuick.Controls 2.5

ApplicationWindow {
   ...

   Item {
     // This Item is to provide needed properties for functionality in the original app that was elided out in this example.
     // It was left in in case it's relevant to the problem.
     ...

     Column {           
        ...

        Text {
           text: qsTr("Masked text")

           SlidingMask {
              id: testMask
              anchors.fill: parent                    
              ...
           }
        }

        Row {
           Button {
              id: btnRevealText
              text: qsTr("Reveal")
              ...
           }

           Button {
              id: btnHideText
              text: qsTr("Hide")
              ...
           }
        }
     }
  }

  Connections {
     target: btnRevealText
     onPressed: testMask.reveal()
  }

  Connections {
     target: btnHideText
     onPressed: testMask.hide()
  }
}
```

And this SlidingMask.qml that's registered in the qml.qrc:

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Rectangle {
           ...

           function hide() {
                            ...
           }
           function reveal() {
                            ...
           }
}
```

When I run the app and try to press the buttons, I get the following errors:

```
TypeError: Property 'hide' of object SlidingMask_QMLTYPE_7(0x19991132c50) is not a function
TypeError: Property 'reveal' of object SlidingMask_QMLTYPE_7(0x19991132c50) is not a function
```

However, if I try changing the Connections to alter a property of the SlidingMask instead of calling a function, it works fine.

I've also tested this component previously and didn't run into any problems then, although I wasn't using Connections in that test.

I've searched here and on Google for an answer, but nothing I've found seems relevant to my situation. How would I fix this?

Comment: Move your javaScript functions into the same scope where the id is defined.

Comment: The functions are part of the SlidingMask component. As far as I'm aware they can't be put somewhere else.

Comment: you can put the JavaScript functions in any QML object, try it.

Comment: What I meant was, the functions are an integral part of the mask's functionality, and it wouldn't make sense to define them somewhere outside the mask. It may be possible, but it wouldn't be a good idea from a design point of view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple example which works properly:

```
//main.qml
ApplicationWindow {
    id: window
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true

    Column{
        ItemWithFunction{
            id: sc
            width: 100
            height: 100
        }

        Button{
            id: btn1
            text: 'Test Connection'
        }
    }

    Connections{
        target: btn1
        onPressed: sc.testFunction();
    }

}
```

```
//ItemWithFunction.qml
Rectangle{
    color: 'red'

    function testFunction(){
        console.log("SOMETHING HAPPENED")
    }
}
```

It seems that you are ***not*** putting your functions in `SlidingMask` root but in one of its child components.

Comment: You're right, thank you. The mask is comprised of two rectangles, one transparent one that acts to maintain the mask's size, and the actual masking rectangle that changes size to scroll in/out to mask the object. The functions are defined in the inner rectangle. I'll have to change that.